# Prove the monotonicity of the expectation of a binary random variable function

Tags: probability, random-variables, absolute-value

Consider $R$ independent binary random variables $y^1, \ldots, y^R$ over the space $\{-1, +1\}$ such that $\Pr(y^j = 1) = p^j \geq 0.5$ and $\Pr(y^j = -1) = 1 - p^j$, $\forall j = 1,\ldots,R$. Moreover, let $\mathcal{J}$ denote a subset of $\mathcal{Y} = \{1, \ldots, R\}$, i.e., $\mathcal{J} \subseteq \mathcal{Y}$. I would like to prove that:

$f(\mathcal{J} \cup \{j'\}) \geq f(\mathcal{J}) \quad \forall \mathcal{J} \in 2^{\mathcal{Y}}, \forall j' \in \mathcal{Y} \setminus \mathcal{J}$

where the function $f( \cdot )$ is defined as follows:

$f(\mathcal{J}) = E\left(| \sum_{j \in \mathcal{J}} y^j  |\right)$

In other words, I want to verify that the afore-mentioned expectation is monotonically non decreasing in the set $\mathcal{J}$. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I posed a new question about the same proof in case $f(\mathcal{J})$ is altered so that $f(\mathcal{J}) = E\left(| \sum_{j \in \mathcal{J}} logit(p^j) y^j  |\right)$. The new question can be found here: [Where is the fallacy in this coupling argument of two Bernoulli variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425481/where-is-the-fallacy-in-this-coupling-argument-of-two-bernoulli-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result holds. By induction on $R$, it suffices to show that if $X=Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$ for independent $\pm1$ Bernoulli random variables $(Y_k)$ with $P[Y_k=1]=p_k\geqslant\frac12$, and if $Y$ is a $\pm1$ Bernoulli random variable independent of $(Y_k)$ with $P[Y=1]=p\geqslant\frac12$, then 
$$
E[|X+Y|]\geqslant E[|X|]. 
$$
Note that $E[|X+Y|]=pE[|X+1|]+(1-p)E[|X-1|]$ and that, for every integer $x$, 
$$
p|x+1|+(1-p)|x-1|-|x|=\mathbf 1_{x=0}+(2p-1)(\mathbf 1_{x\gt0}-\mathbf 1_{x\lt0}).
$$
Since $2p-1\geqslant0$ and $X$ is integer valued, $E[|X+Y|]\geqslant E[|X|]$ as soon as
$$
P[X\gt0]\geqslant P[X\lt0].
$$
The last inequality above is not a priori obvious, fortunately it stems from *a coupling argument*.

To wit, one can assume that, for each $k$, $Y_k=2\mathbf 1_{U_k\leqslant p_k}-1$ where the sequence $(U_k)$ is i.i.d. uniform on the interval $(0,1)$. Let $Y^0_k=2\mathbf 1_{U_k\leqslant\frac12}-1$, then $Y_k^0\leqslant Y_k$ almost surely and the sequence $(Y^0_k)$ is i.i.d. symmetric Bernoulli. In particular, the distribution of $X^0=Y^0_1+\cdots+Y^0_k$ is symmetric hence $P[X^0\gt0]=P[X^0\lt0]$.

Finally, $X^0\leqslant X$ almost surely hence $[X^0\gt0]\subseteq[X\gt0]$ and $[X\lt0]\subseteq[X^0\lt0]$. 
Thus, $P[X\gt0]\geqslant P[X^0\gt0]=P[X^0\lt0]\geqslant P[X\lt0]$, and we are done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The critial steps are when you say that $Y_k^0 \leq Y_k$ and $X^0 \leq X$ hold _almost surely_. It seems that a formal proof should verify that $P(X^0 \leq X) = 1$. Moreover, I'm experiencing some difficulties with the notation, what do you mean by stating that $[X^0\gt0]\subseteq[X\gt0]$? Thanks.

Comment: The formal proof is in my answer: surely you see why $Y^0_k\leqslant Y_k$ almost surely and why this entails that $X^0\leqslant X$ almost surely. Notation: $[X\gt0]=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\gt0\}$ and similarly for the other occurrences.

Comment: I am not so confident in coupling arguments, and most probably I interpreted the expression _almost surely_ in a naive way. By taking a look at wikipedia ( [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(probability)#Biased_coins) ), it seems that for each $k = 1, \ldots, n$, the variable $Y_k^0$ and $Y_k$ can be coupled so that if $Y_k^0 = 1$ then $Y^k = 1$, while if $Y_k^0 = -1$ then $Y_k = +1$ with probability $\frac{p_k - 0.5}{0.5}$. This should entail that $P(X>0) > P(X<0)$. Could you please clarify a little bit that step of the proof? thanks.

Comment: Naive ways are allright but could you clarify which steps of my proof need clarification? (Note that outside information is not needed here and that you can omit the word "coupling" if you want, since I provide the full construction of $Y_k$ and $Y_k^0$ which guarantees that $P[X^0\leqslant X]=1$.)

Comment: As I said, the misunderstanding arises from the fact that it is the first time that I encounter the expression 'almost surely' in the context of probability theory (moreover, english is not my mothertongue). [This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) clarified your statement. Thanks

Comment: What if I slightly change the definition of $f(\cdot)$ from $f(\mathcal{J}) = E\left(| \sum_{j \in \mathcal{J}} y^j  |\right)$ to $f(\mathcal{J}) = E\left(| \sum_{j \in \mathcal{J}} logit(p^j) y^j  |\right)$. In this case, I think that the coupling argument is not valid anymore, since the distribution is still symmetric but $P(X^0 > 0) = 0 = P(X^0 < 0)$. Thanks.

Comment: New problem $\implies$ new question on the site.

Comment: You are perfectly right. In case no solution comes to my mind, I will pose a new question. Thanks.

Comment: I posed a new question. The link is provided at the end of the current question.

Answer (score 0):

wlog $\mathcal T = 1,...,n,.X = \sum^n Y_j, j^{\prime} = n+1$, and that is wlog because you can always go from a smaller set to a larger adding one index at a time, and just number them in the order in which you want to add.
First use Jensen's inequalty/ submartingales to show that if you add a symmetric $Y_{n+1} $ the expected value of the absolute value increases.  Then use the following argument to show that if $\mathbb P (X > 0) > \mathbb P ( X < 0), \mathbb E(|X + Y_{n+1}|) $ is an increasing function of $p_{n+1}$

let $X$ be integer valued, $Y$ be $\pm 1$ with $\mathbb P(Y=1) = p$.  $\mathbb E (|X + Y|) = \mathbb P (X=0) + \sum_{k  > 0} \mathbb P(X = k)((k+1) p + (k-1) (1-p)+ \mathbb P(X = -k)((k+1) (1-p) +( k-1)p)$.

$\frac  d {dp}$ of that is something like  $ 2 \sum_{k > 0} (\mathbb P (X=k) - \mathbb P(X=-k))$ which  is  positive in your case.  Also, if $p_j = \frac 12$ the expectation is larger by the fact that $|X|, |X+Y_j|$ is a submartingale.

Comment: I initially thought $(P(X=k)−P(X=−k) > 0$ was obvious, it may not be, but I only need $P(X > 0) > P(X < 0)$ and that is obvious, since you can modify the symmetric sum ($p_j = \frac 12$) by throwing in some extra 1's.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the typesetting is not of great help. May I ask you to deepen the steps composing your proof?

Comment: Thank you for reformulating your explanation. By using the Jensen's inequality, I can state that: $E\left(|X + Y^{n+1}|\right) \geq |E\left(X + Y^{n+1}\right)| = |E(X) + E(Y^{n+1})| = |E(X) + (2p^{n+1} - 1)|$. What do you mean when you say _simmetric_ $Y^{n+1}$? Given that $X$ is defined as the sum of some $Y^j$, I also do not understand your explanation on why $P(X > 0) > P(X < 0)$ should be obvious, and why such a condition should be required. Thanks.

Comment: symmetic: $ p = \frac 12$,   note that jensen gives you  your inequality only in that case, so you need and extra argument to show that if you increase p your expectation increases.  I say 'obvious' because if all $p_j = \frac 12$ then  $\sum Y_j$ is symmetric and $P(X>0) = P(X < 0)$,  To get to case where some or all $p_j > \frac 12 $ simply change some of the -1's to 1's, i.e. you can get $p=\frac 34$ by generating the symmetric one and flipping -is to 1's with probability $\frac 12$.  Adding ones increases the probability that $X > 0$ and decreases $P(X < 0)$

Comment: I agree with you that if $p^j=0.5$, $\forall j=1, \ldots, n$, then $P(X>0)=P(X<0)$. However, I don't understand your explanation for the general case, i.e., $p^j > 0.5$ for some $j=1,…,n$. With respect to your example, let us alter $p^\hat{j}$ so that $p^\hat{j} = \frac{3}{4}$. At this point you claim that the $P(X>0)$ increases while the $P(X<0)$ decreases. However, I do not understand your explanation on why this should happen. Specifically, what do you mean by "you can get $p^\hat{j}=\frac{3}{4}$ by generating the symmetric one and flipping -1s to 1s with probability $\frac{1}{2}$"?

Comment: Technically, you can check that if $Y_j = \pm 1 $ with probability $\frac 12 $  each, $Y_1 1_{Y_1 = 1} + Y_1 Y_2 1_{Y_1 = -1} $ is 1 with prob $\frac 34$ and $-1 $ otherwise.  Non-technically, you are flipping some of the -1's.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I still don't understand your argument. First, why are you interested in the expression $Y_1 \mathbf{1}_{Y_1 = 1} + Y_1 Y_2 \mathbf{1}_{Y_1 = -1}$? Second, such an expression can be equal only to 0 (if $Y_1 = +1$), 1 (if $Y_1 = -1$ and $Y_2 = -1$) or -2 (if $Y_1 = -1$ and $Y_2 = +1$). Thanks.