# Does $E[X]\gg E[Y]$ for independent RV imply that $Pr[X+Y \geq x] \sim Pr[ X \geq x]$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, asymptotics, approximation, expectation

We have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, where we know that
$E[X]\gg E[Y]$, thus $\frac{E[Y]}{E[X]}\rightarrow 0$.

I am now interested in 
$Pr[X+Y \geq x]$ and would like to show that
$$Pr[X+Y \geq x] \sim Pr[X \geq x]$$
for $x=O(1)$.

$X$ and $Y$ are both sums of independent Bernoulli random variables, thus $X=\sum_i X_i$ and $Y=\sum_j Y_j$ where $X_i, Y_j$ are independent.

I tried to use the first moment method on $\frac{X}{Y}$ and also tried to extract the case where $Y=0$ but this all does not help. Would really appreciate if you could give me a hint, as small as it may be. 
To write
$$Pr[X+Y \geq x] = Pr[X \geq x] Pr[Y=0] + Pr[X=0] Pr[Y \geq x]+....$$
was my idea, but i don't see how this should help me.

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847369/if-x-leq-x-almost-surely-is-it-possible-to-prove-that-px-s-geq-px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Let $X=10$ be a constant and $Y$ take two values, $100$ and $-100$, with equal probabilities. Then $E(X)=10\gg 0=E(Y)$, but $P(X>15)=0$ while $P(X+Y)>15=1/2$.

I don't think you can get a "universal" inequality for *all* $x$. 
Take $x$ such that $P(X>x)$ is small but $P(Y>x)$ is large.
This does *not* contradict your condition on the expectations as is easily seen from the two examples you got.

What you would probably need is something like $P(X\gg Y)\approx 1$.

Note that the probability of density of $X+Y$ is the [Convolution of their individual probability densities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) (which is a more complicated formula that the one you are trying to use).

Comment: So you deleted your comment about the variance. 

Is there something else I could assume in order to prove that?
What I really would like to show:
I have two sets from which I get some edges to a certain node. I know that the expected number of edges $E[X]$ from one set is much bigger than from the other set $E[Y]$. So I'd like to show that in order to compute the probability of a lower bound ond the number of edges, it is asymptotically enough to consider just the first set. 
So no chance to do that?

Comment: I replaced my condition with a stronger one

Comment: as I am a little bit bad in probability: do you know whether one can show this, when 
$X:=\sum_{i=1}^{k} Bin( n (1/2)^i, i)$ and
$Y:=\sum_{i=k+1}^{\infty} Bin(n (1/2)^i, i)$, where we can choose $k\gg 1$ arbitrary.

Comment: yes, I am pretty sure we can show that. Please ask that question separately.

Comment: Ok, I will ask it and link it. So could you post how to solve this problem under this assumption? Would be great!

Comment: here's the link to the new proof question: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871032/prove-prx-y-geq-x-sim-prx-geq-x

Comment: here's the link to the proof of the assumption:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871051/show-that-prx-gg-y-approx-1

Answer (score 1):

A counter example with non-negative random variables would be when $Y$ is identically $1$ and $X$ is $0$ with probability $0.9$ and $10^{10}$ with probability $0.1$. Then $P(X + Y > x) = 1$ when $x < 1$, but $P(X > x) = 0.1$.