# Show that $Pr[X \gg Y]\approx 1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, asymptotics

Can one show (and how) that 
$$Pr[X \gg Y]\approx 1$$
for 
$$X:=\sum_{i=1}^k Bin\left(n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i,i\right)$$ and
$$Y:=\sum_{i=k+1}^{\infty} Bin\left(n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i,i\right)$$
where one can choose $k \gg 1$ arbitrarily.

Comment: sorry, I've made a mistake. I've edited it now.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? If not, then it is possible to make counterexamples.

Comment: X and Y are independent and Bin means Binomial distribution.
One could rewrite $X=\sum_i X_i$ for $X_i \sim Bin(n \frac{1}{2^i},i)$ if you wish.

Comment: shouldn't it be $Bin(i,i/2^i)$? iow, what is $n$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $b_n=\text{Bin}(n,n/2^n)$. 
Then $E(b_n)=n^2/2^2$, $\text{Var}(b_n)=(1-n/2^n)n^2/2^n$, and the series $\sum b_n$ converges in $L_2$. 
This means that $Y_k=\sum_{k+1}^\infty b_n$ converges to $0$ - and thus is smaller than $X$ most of the time.